# Set OnDetach event handler programmatically

Tags: google-app-maker

The app I'm building uses an external library, **[EasyTimer.js](https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/#chronometerExample)**. It is useful for timers. I use an HTML widget to show how much time it has elapsed since the timer started, thus it looks like this:

[image]

It actually works really good! The only problem I'm having is that I need to stop the timer when the page is detached; that is because the record will be changed and thus the timer needs to start again. Not doing so, causes conflicts with the timer.

On the HTML widget onAttach event, I have this:

```
//start running timer in the HTML widget
var runningTimer = new Timer();
runningTimer.start({precision: 'seconds', startValues: {seconds: startSeconds}});
runningTimer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
  $('#timerDiv').html(timerRun.getTimeValues().toString());
});

//attach event listener to page onDetach event to stop timer
widget.root.getElement().addEventListener("unload", function(){
    runningTimer.stop();
    console.log("Timer stopped");
)};
```

The top part of the code is working, the bottom one does nothing. I have examined the [**widget logic documentation**](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#Events), but there is no hint as to if this is possible or not.

I have a feeling that this might not be possible and I'm starting to freak out; Nonetheless, I wanted to consult with an expert here in case there is a solution and I just haven't found it.

For your valuable time and opinion on this matter, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is such a noob question, but how do I get the library for this into App Maker? I was going to try it myself to see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa the info is here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings#app_start

Comment: I guess let me clarify, did you put a URL for the library into App Maker external resources JavaScript URLs and if so what was the URL, or did you put this <script src="lib/easytimer/dist/easytimer.min.js"></script> in the app start up script?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa ahh, that you mean. Here is the library url https://rawgit.com/albert-gonzalez/easytimer.js/master/dist/easytimer.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, **it is not possible to set the onDetach event handler programmatically**; Nevertheless, I found a possible solution for you by implementing a custom property on the page. I used a property of type Dynamic and named it 'Timer' for this example. I did not implement Jquery library for this, but used the HTML widget options instead. Here is the html widget onAttach event code:

```
//start running timer in the HTML widget
widget.root.properties.Timer = new Timer();
var runningTimer = widget.root.properties.Timer;
runningTimer.start({precision: 'seconds', startValues: {seconds: 0}});
runningTimer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
  widget.html = runningTimer.getTimeValues().toString();
});
```

Here is the page onDetach event code:

```
widget.root.properties.Timer.stop();
```

Hope this will work for you or get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Honestly, I've never used the dynamic property so I was not sure on how to use it. Thanks for this. I learnt something new.

Comment: @Morfinismo I've started implementing it somewhat frequently since it appears to be impractical or even impossible to implement global type variables in App Maker. I believe that is why your code might not have been working in the Detach event, since your running timer was not recognized as global, rather specific to the widget. That is one part I'm still trying to figure out in regards to App Maker.

Comment: Well, I found a solution. I was using `window.runningTimmer = null;` on the onAttach event hence I did not had to add the onDetach event programmatically. Then on the onDetach I just used `if(runningTimmer) { runningTimmer.stop(); }`. However, I like your solution better.